# Excel - present word between certain characters

Tags: string, excel, break, formulas

I am trying to split some data up but stuck! I have some data which comes out like the below:

`USERNAME       Full Name      Department`

`USERNAME   First Initial Surname      Department`

`USERNAME           Full Name     Department`

I have tried numerous items such as trim then can pull out words however some peoples full names are 3 words and most of them are 2 words so this kinda breaks it all.

I have also tried substituting the double spaces so it breaks it up like so

`##USERNAME#######Full Name######Department###########`

`##USERNAME###First Initial Surname      Department#`

`##USERNAME###########Full Name#####Department#####`

But still unsure how I can pick up the words between the hashes.

Help really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a text file with the raw data, separate the raw data using either of a TAB, a semi-colon, or a comma. Pick something you do not already have in your file. Semi-colon usually works for me.

Then, open it as a CSV (comma-separated values) file in Excel.

[image: Open File as CSV in Excel]

It will try to parse the file automatically. If it doesn't succeed, it will ask you what character you want to use as a separator.

Comment: The data is coming from SQL via a connection so I need to do it within excel via a formula where possible as this is going to be used by other people.

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect it? Sorry I couldn't be of any further help...

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned double spaces seperating your data, that's your ticket in.

Let's say you've got "USERNAME  David Brossard  DEPT" in Cell A2.

In B2, let's FIND the first double space:

```
=FIND("  ",A2)
```

In C2, let's FIND the second double space:

```
=FIND("  ",A2,B2+1)
```

In D2, we'll grab everything in between:

```
=MID(A2,B2+2,C2-(B2+2))
```

There you go!

Alternatively, you can write it all in one formula, in B2:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("  ",A2)+2,FIND("  ",A2,FIND("  ",A2)+1)-(FIND("  ",A2)+2))
```

Comment: Note: Stack Overflow's formatting removed the double spaces from my example string, but I intended double spaces between USERNAME, David Brossard, and DEPT.